# wait for workflow not equal to is not available in sp 2013 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I was surprised to find out in SharePoint 2013 wait for item not equal to is not available in sharepoint 2013.

is there a work around. In my sinario there are two options approved or rejected to go to the next stage? before i could just do a "Wait for status not equal to value" to move to the next stage. How do i do this in Sharepoint Designer 2013 workflow

Comment: Are you trying to wait until the value isn't blank?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to wait until the variable has a value, you can do mimic this functionality by using a Parallel Block.

Set up parallel actions for each of the scenarios which should allow you to continue through the workflow. In each of these wait for your value to equal one of the correct results, and then set a boolean variable to Yes. Right click the parallel block, and choose Advanced Properties, and set your variable as the Completion Condition. The below screenshot is one where I was waiting for a field called Stage to equal 1, 2, 3 or 4.

[image]

When the workflow enters this block, it will pause until one of the parallel conditions is met, then continue. Any other parallel actions will be terminated at that point.

Comment: here is my story. i have a business card approval workflow. once the user has submitted it will go to the administrators who approves or reject it, then it goes to the manager who again approves or rejects it finally it will to to the reprographics team who takes care of the request. when the request first sent an email will be fired and status field of the list will be changed to "Administrator" and wait till the status changes to "Manager" if he approves or "Administrator reject" if he reject this goes on to the next level of approval as well. it is straightforward in SPD 2010.

Comment: can you show me a sample of how to do it in 2013? this is my first time in SPD 2013